# Download the output of a command line program using PuTTy/WinSCP

Tags: windows-7, linux, ssh, mysql, putty

I have ssh-access to a linux server. My account is running out of free space and I am forced to remove some data from the server. I would love to download my mysql database (and delete if afterwards) but because I have no more space I can not dump my database using `mysqldump` to my `~`.

Is it possible to download the `stdout` of a remote linux system using PuTTY/WinSCP on my windows 7 machine? So I could directly download the output of `mysqldump` without saving to the harddisk of the remote system? Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full PuTTY package has `plink`, although I'm not sure how well it works with password prompts:

```
plink -C user@host "mysqldump -uroot -p db1" > C:\Backup\db1.sql

plink user@host "mysqldump -uroot -p db1 | gzip" > C:\Backup\db1.sql.gz
```

Comment: Worked perfect without `-p`.